# Ошибка с git pull

Tags: git, git-pull

пытаюсь переместить файлы из репозитория на сервер, для этого выполняю команду git pull origin master. это выдает мне ошибку: CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Auto-merging CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result. Можете объяснить, почему возникает и как её исправить.

Comment: по разным причинам, у вас если конфликты между ветками или у вас текущая ветка не master или что-то ещё

Comment: Запустите `git pull --rebase origin master` -- будет немного яснее, где именно по истории выпадает в осадок.